# I can't send a Facebook game request using Graph API v2.8

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-app-requests, facebook-graph-api-v2.8

I've spent a lot of time trying to send a game request from the (latest) JS API, using the Graph API v2.8, but nothing seems to work.

I've used only common OG, since custom OG are deprecated. When I use "turn" instead of "send" as the action type, my request works, since the "turn" requests don't require an object id, so I guess the problem comes from my OG.

I first created an action like this:

```
curl -X POST \
-F "access_token=*a user access token*" \
-F "game=*my game id*" \
    https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/me/games.plays
```

And then sent a game request using it the returned id in the "object_id" field. And this is the result I got:

[Facebook response after calling FB.ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUGYb.png)

Which doesn't provide any information...
So I tried to make a game object instead of an action. I figured "maybe you can't use actions in this context", and since game.achievement is the ONLY game object available, I made an achievement object, like this:

```
curl -X POST \
    -F "access_token=*my app access token*" \
    -F "object={\"fb:app_id\":\"*my app id*\",\"og:type\":\"game.achievement\",\"og:url\":\"*object's URL*\",\"og:title\":\"*A title*\",\"og:description\":\"*A description*\",\"og:image\":\"*A link to an image*\",\"game:points\":\"1\"}" \
        https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/app/objects/game.achievement
```

This is the result that I got:

[Facebook response after calling FB.ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nabTv.png)

Which makes no sense, because the object was created using an app access token, and that my app IS a game. So this statement makes no sense.

And now, I'm lost. I have no solution left, no new idea to try. I don't know what to do... The documentation is obviously missing information. They didn't even bother making a documentation for the games.plays action...

I need someone who knows how to use this damned API to help me figure this out, because right now, I'm just completely stuck.

Thanks in advance, community.

Comment: no answer? Im implementing this n having the not owned by app error too!

Comment: Do you guys have answers already? I'm stuck also with his one